# Python series if condition return ValueError:

Tags: python, pandas

my code return `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I want to compare two dates, if the latest date, do something

```
dlast= datetime.strptime(df.index[-1], '%Y-%m-%d')
dnow = pd.to_datetime(date_mode, format='%Y, %m, %d').dt.date

if dlast<dnow:
     print "yes yes"
```

Error occurred at the if statement where `dlast` and `dnow` unable to compare

```
    >>> type(dlast)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> dlast
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 26, 0, 0)
>>> dnow
0    2020-02-28
Name: trading_day, dtype: object
>>> type(dnow)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> df.index[-1]
'2020-02-26'
>>> type(df.index[-1])
<type 'str'>
>>> date_mode
0   2020-02-28
Name: trading_day, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> type(date_mode)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: I think `if (dlast<dnow).any():` would work.

Comment: This is pandas, right? If so, add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to overload the ">". Check out this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/ on operator overloading in python

Edit: Since I was not clear, here is a working solution to overcome this issue. I understand it's not the prettiest, but it's a solution that can generally be applied in most languages when dealing with type-mismatch:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

date_mode = pd.Series("2020, 02, 28", index=[0])
dlast= datetime.strptime("2020-02-26", '%Y-%m-%d')
dnow = pd.to_datetime(date_mode, format='%Y, %m, %d').dt.date

class A: 
    def __init__(self, a): 
        self.a = a 
    def __lt__(self, other): 
        if(self.a.year < other.a[0].year): 
            return True
        elif(self.a.year == other.a[0].year):
            if(self.a.month < other.a[0].month): 
                return True
            elif(self.a.month == other.a[0].month):
                if(self.a.day < other.a[0].day):
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

obj1 = A(dlast)
obj2 = A(dnow)
if(obj1 < obj2):
    print("yes yes")
```

Comment: I think this is `pandas` and the operator already is overloaded. I don't see how this will help.

Comment: @tdelaney, you're correct in that I wasn't clear what I meant. I've updated my solution with a working example

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be: you want to get the value of date, but Pandas returns you a Series with a bunch of information.

Maybe you can try something like dlast.values[0], so you will probably get the date.